# CSS in Lightning Web Component: Change Label position on focus

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, css, html

I am trying to move the label position on focus of form inputbox. This is the code I am trying to write in CSS. If the inputbox is focused, it should change the label too. SEE ERROR LINE. Please help.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form__group field">
    <input type="input" class="form__field" placeholder="Name" name="name" id='name' required />
    <label for="name" class="form__label">Name</label>
</div>
```

**CSS-**

```
.form__field:focus {
   &.form__label {   //ERROR LINE
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.2s;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #11998e;
    font-weight:700;    
  }
  padding-bottom: 6px;  
  font-weight: 700;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #11998e ,#38ef7d);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use case , you need [focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) pseudo class.

**What's special about `focus-within` pseudo class ?**

- It gives the ability to select the parent or descendants based on the state(focus) of child element(s).

For the same markup , you can use below css :

```
.form__field:focus {
 padding-bottom: 6px;
 font-weight: 700;
 border-width: 3px;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #11998e ,#38ef7d);
 border-image-slice: 1;
}

/* Select the label which is contained in the div */
.form__group:focus-within label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.2s;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #11998e;
  font-weight:700;
}
```

Here , we check for focus inside the outer `div` element and modify the css for the containing `label`.

**Edit** : Instead of using `.form__group:focus-within label` selector , you can also select by label class - `.form__group:focus-within .form__label`

Comment: It solved my problem partially. I had to convert this SCSS code to CSS in order to make it work in the LWC environment. I will mark this as an answer for the approach. Thank you once again. :)